# Registering an ELB to an ECS service with random host port

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elb

I'm working with the ECS service on AWS and I have this problem - the docker containers I need to run on ECS are webservices, each container should have its internal port 80 mapped to a random port on the container host. I don't want to specify the host port for the 80 container port beforehand, I'd like to let docker daemon to find a host port for the container.

But, how the ELB fits here? For me it looks that I have to know the host port to be able to create the ELB for the service.

Is it so?

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible using [Application load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/)

However, if you need to open up inbound traffic on the security group, security group's port mapping is not updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

ELB does not allow binding to random port.

We have recently implemented service discovery with ECS and CONSUL. We had to introduce [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) as intermediate layer between the ELB and our apps.

ELB maps to zuul on a static port, but Zuul discovers the backend services dynamically and routes traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You need a service discovery system, such as [Hashicorp's Consul](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul) and then you need to integrate it with AWS infrastructure: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/service-discovery-via-consul-with-amazon-ecs/

Comment: Service discovery is one thing, but how does it help with integration of the ELB and a container?
I'm just wondering if there is a way how to ensure that a randomly picked host port for a container matches with an ELB instance port.

Comment: Consul doesn't help with the ELB issue -- ELBs cannot deal with randomized ports.  You could though forgo ELBs for internally facing apps and integrate with Consul instead.